# Improve PySpark implementation for finding connected components in a graph

Tags: pyspark, bigdata, databricks, connected-components

I am currently working on the implementation of this paper describing Map Reduce Algorithm to fing connected component : [https://www.cse.unr.edu/~hkardes/pdfs/ccf.pdf](https://www.cse.unr.edu/%7Ehkardes/pdfs/ccf.pdf)
As a beginner in Big Data world , I started the implementation of CCF-Iterate (w. secondary sorting) algorithm with a small graph : 6 edges and 8 nodes. I'm running this code with the free version of Databricks.

It takes 1 minute to give a result. That seems too long for a such small example . How can I reduce this time ? What kind of optimization is possible? Any advice would be really apreciated.
The idea is to test this algo for large graphs

PySpark code:

```
graph = sc.parallelize([ (2,3),(1,2), (2,4), (3,5), (6,7),(7,8)])
counter_new_pair = sc.accumulator(1)

while (counter_new_pair.value > 0):
  
  counter_new_pair = sc.accumulator(0)

  #CCF Iterate Sorting
  mapping_1 = graph.map(lambda x : (x[0], x[1]))
  mapping_2 = graph.map(lambda x : (x[1], x[0]))
  fusion = mapping_1.union(mapping_2)
  fusion = fusion.groupByKey().map(lambda x : (x[0], list(x[1])))

  fusion = fusion.map(lambda x : (x[0], sorted(x[1])))
  values = fusion.filter(lambda x : x[1][0] < x[0])
  
  key_min_value = values.map(lambda x : (x[0], x[1][0]))
  values = values.map(lambda x : (x[1][0], x[1][1:]))
  values = values.filter(lambda x : len(x[1]) != 0)
  values = values.flatMap(lambda x : [(val, x[0]) for val in x[1]])
  values.foreach(lambda x: counter_new_pair.add(1))
  joined = values.union(key_min_value)

  # CCF Dedup

  mapping = joined.map(lambda x : ((x[0], x[1]), None))
  graph = mapping.groupByKey().map(lambda x : (x[0][0], x[0][1]))
```

Thanks

Comment: I suggest using GraphFrames for graph computations with Spark dataframes. GraphFrames already implement connected component calculations in their Python API.

Comment: @ mck thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately I must not use this library for this project.